# JSON parse DateTime

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, wcf, json.net

From the server I get this string

```
[{\"id\":\"9b77ff1e-350e-44d8-8860-15e80f4d8a22\",\"code\":\"C\",\"name\":\"0%\",\"validFrom\":\"2013-07-01T00:00:00Z\",\"validTill\":null,\"active\":1,\"vatProc\":0.0,\"createdAt\":\"2015-02-01T13:04:17.733Z\",\"updatedAt\":\"2015-02-01T13:04:17.733Z\"}]
```

On the client side I then convert it to a json object using JSON.parse which produces the result:

```
[
{
active:1
code:"C"
createdAt:"2015-02-01T13:04:17.733Z"
id:"9b77ff1e-350e-44d8-8860-15e80f4d8a22"
name:"0%"
updatedAt:"2015-02-01T13:04:17.733Z"
validFrom:"2013-07-01T00:00:00Z"
validTill:null
vatProc:0
}
]
```

Which is as you would expect if it where not for the date fields.

The dates are on server translated to UTC.

I know I can pass a function to parse the function to do the conversion.
I would just like to format the date's so that the regular parse would do it "right" if you know what I mean

I saw on the net that there is no "right" way and that every case what I was reading about on the net is working with conversion on the client side.

So is there really no way to tell the regular json parser that that is a date?

I have the option to convert that date-time to what ever would work on the server

**ClientSide:** AngularJS

**ServerSide:** C# WCF / json

**EDIT:**

The problem that I am having is that if I use for instance the `ValidFrom` as a model in AngularJS it is complaining that it is not a date witch it really is not

AngularJS error:

```
Expected `2013-07-01T00:00:00Z` to be a date
```

Comment: What *is* the question? The two texts are the same. The dates haven't changed. `Z` means that they *are* UTC. What did you expect as a result? Please post the *code* you used, what the result was and what did you expect. Did you get a DateTime whose DateTimeKind property *wasn't* UTC? Did you expect to get a local time? Why don't you use the DateTime object you already have?

Comment: You can convert from UTC to your "local" time with `.ToLocalTime()` but that *does* change with DST

Comment: More info in the edit

Comment: will try with a angular parser to transform it. Still don't like it but looks like the only plausible way

Answer (score 2):

Before I send a date to the client I set the DateTimeKind property to utc

```
SomeObject.Date=  DateTime.SpecifyKind(SomeObject.Date, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Before saving any date to the server I do:

```
SomeObject.Date=  SomeObject.Date.ToUniversalTime();
```

The only requirement on the client is to use momentjs format() method in order to convert the date to ISO-8601

Following this method JSON always handles times correctly on the client (at least it has worked fine so far for me)

[This helped me a lot](http://thewebjedi.com/be/post/2014/02/22/dates-and-time-zones-in-javascript-c-and-sql-server.aspx)

Comment: In other words, use UTC throughout. An even better solution would be to use DateTimeOffset instead of making any conversions

Comment: I tryed your aproach but that resulted in the same output from the server

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial, using moment.js and all?

Comment: Thank you nice to know about moment.js but that would be a client side solution I would like to use as little JS as possible if I have to I will but I would like to find a server side solution if there is one like I said in the question

Comment: Yeah I'd like that too